# Reference child element of an Aggregate Root?

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have a Unit Class that act as a Entity *(Aggregate Root)* and this class must have reference to Province and City. I have put Province and city in a class called Region *(Aggregate Root)* and this class is Entity too. every province has its own cities and their names and relations are permanent and can't be changed.

so until now I have **two aggregate root**, Unit and Region. but in Unit I need to have reference to province and city, but in DDD term I just can reference to root of my aggregate and in this case it is province and I can't have reference to child of province !

how to solve this problem and how to have reference from unit to province and city ?

Comment: `Province` and `City` should be aggregate roots. Why did you cluster them with `Region`?

Comment: Tnx @plalx for your reply but city by itself has no meaning, I mean city is child of Province and it can't be alone. in IRAN we have Province and then cities.

Comment: If it has no meaning, why do you want to link that concept with something else than a `Province`? What makes you think it has no meaning by itself? A city references it's `Region` by identity and has an identity of it's own. Aggregates are abount transactionnal boundaries and invariants enforcement. What problem are you trying to solve by having a collection of cities in `Region`?

Comment: In DDD, you do not cluster things together just because you have statements like "regions have cities".

Comment: Thank you @plalx, by your help I found that my assumption was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the help of [plalx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1211528/plalx) I found that my assumption about DDD was wrong. in this model and models like that I shouldn't hidden cities in Aggregate and they should be both Aggregate Root in seperate Aggregate.